# How to send and receive data in a loop

Tags: fortran, mpi, send

I am facing a problem in sending and receiving data in a do loop. Check the code below:

```
  include 'mpif.h'
  parameter (NRA = 4)
  parameter (NCA = 4)
  parameter (MASTER = 0)
  parameter (FROM_MASTER = 1)
  parameter (FROM_WORKER = 2)

  integer   numtasks,taskid,numworkers,source,dest,mtype,
 &          cols,avecol,extra, offset,i,j,k,ierr,rc
  integer status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
  real*8    a(NRA,NCA)

  call MPI_INIT( ierr )
  call MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_WORLD, taskid, ierr )
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, numtasks, ierr )
  numworkers = numtasks-1  
  print *, 'task ID= ',taskid
C *************************** master task *************************************
  if (taskid .eq. MASTER) then
  if (numworkers .NE. 2) then 
     print *, 'Please use 3 processors'
     print *,'Quitting...'
    call MPI_ABORT(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rc,ierr)
  endif
 C     Initialize A and B 
    do 30 i=1, NRA
      do 30 j=1, NCA
      a(i,j) = (i-1)+(j-1)
30     continue
C     Send matrix data to the worker tasks 
    avecol = NCA/numworkers
    extra = mod(NCA,numworkers)
    offset = 1
    mtype = FROM_MASTER
    do 50 dest=1, numworkers
      if (dest .le. extra) then
        cols = avecol + 1
      else
        cols = avecol
      endif
      write(*,*)'   sending',cols,' cols to task',dest
      call MPI_SEND(offset,1,MPI_INTEGER,dest,mtype, 
 &                   MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
      call MPI_SEND(cols,1,MPI_INTEGER,dest,mtype, 
 &                   MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
      call MPI_SEND(a(1,offset),cols*NRA,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
 &                   dest,mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr )
      offset = offset + cols
50     continue
C     Receive results from worker tasks
    mtype = FROM_WORKER
    do 60 i=1, numworkers
      source = i
      call MPI_RECV(offset,1,MPI_INTEGER,source,
 &                   mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr )
      call MPI_RECV(cols,1,MPI_INTEGER,source,
 &                   mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr )
      call MPI_RECV(a(1,offset),cols*NRA,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 
 &                   source,mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr)
60     continue
C     Print results 
    do 90 i=1, NRA
      do 80 j = 1, NCA
        write(*,70)a(i,j)
70        format(2x,f8.2,$)
80      continue
      print *, ' '
90    continue
  endif
C *************************** worker task *************************************
  if (taskid > MASTER) then
C     Receive matrix data from master task
    mtype = FROM_MASTER
    call MPI_RECV(offset,1,MPI_INTEGER,MASTER,
 &                 mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr)
    call MPI_RECV( cols,1,MPI_INTEGER,MASTER,
 &                 mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr)
    call MPI_RECV(a(1,offset),cols*NCA,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MASTER,
 &                 mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr)
 start0 = offset
 end0 = offset+cols-1
 C     Do matrix multiply
    do t=1,5
      do i=1, NRA
        do j=start0,end0
          a(i,j) = a(i,j)*t
        enddo
      enddo
 C     Send results back to master task
    mtype = FROM_WORKER
    call MPI_SEND(offset,1,MPI_INTEGER,MASTER,mtype, 
 &                 MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
    call MPI_SEND(cols,1,MPI_INTEGER,MASTER,mtype, 
 &                 MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
    call MPI_SEND(a(1,offset),cols*NCA,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MASTER,
 &                  mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
 enddo
  endif
  call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
  end
```

I want to print matrix `a`, every time on the screen which is inside the do loop. When I execute the code, it gets printed for only once, i.e. for the first time of the do loop (`t`=1). How to modify this code, so that I can get the matrix `a` printed every time on the screen once it gets calculated.

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow. Try to keep your question concise. Avoid introductions about yourself and avoid greetings and thanks in advance. It is good to show the output of the program and explain what you want to get.

Comment: @VladimirF matrix a is [  0     1     2     3 ;
     1     2     3     4 ;
     2     3     4     5 ;
     3     4     5     6
]. In a loop it gets multiplied by 1 to 5. I am expecting the result 1*a, 2*a, ..5*a the matrix to be printed on screen. But with the present only 1*a gets printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I have to put a loop at the master while receiving the data from slave. The modified code.

```
  include 'mpif.h'

  parameter (NRA = 4)
  parameter (NCA = 4)
  parameter (MASTER = 0)
  parameter (FROM_MASTER = 1)
  parameter (FROM_WORKER = 2)

  integer   numtasks,taskid,numworkers,source,dest,mtype,
 &          cols,avecol,extra, offset,i,j,k,ierr,rc
  integer status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
  real*8    a(NRA,NCA)

  call MPI_INIT( ierr )
  call MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_WORLD, taskid, ierr )
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, numtasks, ierr )
  numworkers = numtasks-1  
  print *, 'task ID= ',taskid

  C *************************** master task *************************************
  if (taskid .eq. MASTER) then
  if (numworkers .NE. 2) then 
     print *, 'Please use 3 processors'
     print *,'Quitting...'
    call MPI_ABORT(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rc,ierr)
  endif
  C     Initialize A and B 
    do 30 i=1, NRA
      do 30 j=1, NCA
      a(i,j) = (i-1)+(j-1)
 30     continue

 C     Send matrix data to the worker tasks 
    avecol = NCA/numworkers
    extra = mod(NCA,numworkers)
    offset = 1
    mtype = FROM_MASTER
    do 50 dest=1, numworkers
      if (dest .le. extra) then
        cols = avecol + 1
      else
        cols = avecol
      endif
      write(*,*)'   sending',cols,' cols to task',dest
      call MPI_SEND(offset,1,MPI_INTEGER,dest,mtype, 
 &                   MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
      call MPI_SEND(cols,1,MPI_INTEGER,dest,mtype, 
 &                   MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
      call MPI_SEND(a(1,offset),cols*NRA,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
 &                   dest,mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr )
      offset = offset + cols
50     continue

C     Receive results from worker tasks
    do t = 1,5
    mtype = FROM_WORKER
    do 60 i=1, numworkers
      source = i
      call MPI_RECV(offset,1,MPI_INTEGER,source,
 &                   mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr )
      call MPI_RECV(cols,1,MPI_INTEGER,source,
 &                   mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr )
      call MPI_RECV(a(1,offset),cols*NRA,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 
 &                   source,mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr)
60     continue
C     Print results 
    do 90 i=1, NRA
      do 80 j = 1, NCA
        write(*,70)a(i,j)
70        format(2x,f8.2,$)
80      continue
      print *, ' '
90    continue 
    end do


  endif

C *************************** worker task *************************************
  if (taskid > MASTER) then
C     Receive matrix data from master task
    mtype = FROM_MASTER
    call MPI_RECV(offset,1,MPI_INTEGER,MASTER,
 &                 mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr)
    call MPI_RECV( cols,1,MPI_INTEGER,MASTER,
 &                 mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr)
    call MPI_RECV(a(1,offset),cols*NCA,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MASTER,
 &                 mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr)
 start0 = offset
 end0 = offset+cols-1

C     Do matrix multiply
    do t=1,5
      do i=1, NRA
        do j=start0,end0
          a(i,j) = a(i,j)*t
        enddo
      enddo     
 C     Send results back to master task
    mtype = FROM_WORKER
    call MPI_SEND(offset,1,MPI_INTEGER,MASTER,mtype, 
 &                 MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
    call MPI_SEND(cols,1,MPI_INTEGER,MASTER,mtype, 
 &                 MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
    call MPI_SEND(a(1,offset),cols*NCA,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MASTER,
 &                  mtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
 enddo
  endif
  call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
  end
```